# Change the shell anacron uses to run a job?

Tags: linux, cron

Can I change the shell anacron uses to invoke the command?

For example, given the following line in the anacrontab:

```
1 0 some-job echo "hi"
```

Anacron will, by default, run this like `/bin/sh -c 'echo "hi"'`. I'd like it to run (for example) with bash as `/bin/bash -c 'echo "hi"'`.

I've tried changing the `SHELL` in the anacron file, as in:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
1 0 some-job echo "hi"
```

and this indeed changes the `$SHELL` environment inside the job itself (so, for example, things that launch stuff with `$SHELL` will use `/bin/bash`), but it doesn't change the behavior of `anacron` which is still using `/bin/sh -c ...`.

I know I can run `/bin/bash` inside of `/bin/sh`, e.g., by changing the command in the anacrontab file to `1 0 some-job bash -c 'echo "hi"'`, but I'm wondering if I can tell anacron to use `/bin/bash` directly.